# Getting data from Google Spreadsheets

Tags: google-sheets-api

I quickly made a little form in Google Docs that lets people insert the most current attraction wait times at Disneyland and submit them to a Google Spreadsheet. I want to make a web page that will display the bottom, most recent row from that spreadsheet so the current wait time for each attraction is always displayed when someone visits the web page. Is there a possible way already to share and embed just the bottom row of data from the spreadsheet?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hooray for google's api documentation section, although it's hard to sometimes find the right section... I've never done this before but it looks pretty straightforward

for list based feeds
see this: http://code.google.com/apis/spreadsheets/data/3.0/developers_guide.html#ListFeeds
or for cell based feeds
see this: http://code.google.com/apis/spreadsheets/data/3.0/developers_guide.html#CellFeeds

Comment: Thank you @tophersmith116 but the link shows only .NET samples. Please where can I find PHP samples?

Comment: For PHP, use the Zend Framework at http://framework.zend.com/manual/1.12/en/zend.gdata.spreadsheets.html